# Construct an example on product of measurable rectangles

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

In *A Course in Real Analysis*, J.McDonald, N.Weiss (2004), p.233:

Note:

> Let $(\Gamma, \mathcal{S})$ and $(\Lambda, \mathcal{T})$ be measurable spaces. A subset of $\Gamma \times \Lambda$ of the form $S \times T$, where $S \in \mathcal{S}$ and $T \in \mathcal{T}$ is called a measurable rectangle. The collection of all measurable rectangles is denoted by $\mathcal{U}$.

Now there is this Lemma:

> $\textbf{Lemma 4.6}$ : Suppose that $\{C_k\}^{n}_{k=1}$ is a finite sequence of pairwise disjoint members of $\mathcal{U}$ whose union is in $\mathcal{U}$. Then $$\iota\left(\bigcup^{n}_{k=1}C_k\right) = \sum_{k=1}^{n} \iota(C_k),$$ where $\iota(C_k)$ is the measure of set $C_k$.

The proof is as following:

> Set $C = \bigcup\limits_{k=1}^n C_k$. Then by assumption, we can write $C = S \times T$ and $C_k = S_k \times T_k$ (the Cartesian product), for $1 \leq k\leq n$, where $S, S_k \in \mathcal{S}$ and $T, T_k \in \mathcal{T}$.

Question:

Could anyone give me an intuitive example of $C, C_k, S_k, T_k, S, T$?

Comment: Imagine a coordinate system and let $C$ be the union of $[0,1]\times[0,1]$ and $[2,3]\times [2,3]$, which clearly are disjoint. Now $C$ is a union of rectangles and I already gave you the rectangles in form of cartesian products. You can say the intervals are from $\mathcal{T}$ and $\mathcal{S}$ respectively. (Does this help?)

Comment: @calculatormathematical so $S_1 = [0,1]$, $T_1 = [0,1]$, $S_2 = [2,3]$, $T_2 = [2,3]$. What are $S$ and $T$ so that $S \times T = (S_1 \times T_1) \cup (S_2 \times T_2)$?

Comment: Dave, here is a correct example: $C=S\times T=[0,3)\times[0,3)=\bigcup_{k=1}^4C_k,$ $C_1=[0,1)\times[0,1),$ $C_2=[1,3)\times[0,1),$ $C_3=[0,1)\times[1,3),$ $C_4=[1,3)\times[1,3).$

Comment: @AnneBauval ok, your previous example was $[2,3] \times [2,3)$ so $(1.5, 1.5)$ was not correct. Now it seems good to me. Thanks very much!

Comment: As you could see, I corrected that typo just a few seconds after first editing the comment. This example can be easily generalized.

Comment: @calculatormathematical $S$ and $T$ are not squares by taking the cartesian product of the interval. They are only intervals (or union of them). Please take a look at Anna's example which is very clear. You should show explicitly what are $S$ and $T$ in your example, for instance, $S = [0.3)$ (in Anna's example)

Comment: You could take $[01)\times[0,1)$ and $[1,2]\times[0,1)$. Those are rectangles (squares). Then $S=[0,2], T=[0,1)$ are intervals and their cartesian product is a rectangle as it is the set of points $\{(s,t)\mid s\in S, t\in T\}$.

Comment: https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Piet_Mondrian?uselang=en#/media/File:Composition_A_by_Piet_Mondrian_Galleria_Nazionale_d'Arte_Moderna_e_Contemporanea.jpg

Comment: @calculatormathematical now it's good, thanks

Comment: @AnneBauval sorry for typing your name incorrectly, I can not edit the previous post any more